# Japanese encoding (phpmyadmin)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

When I request my table that contains japanese symbols set in utf8_unicode_ci, they show instead question marks. How can I make it show the Japanese symbols properly ?

[image]

PHP :

```
<?php

    $query = " SELECT * FROM `kana` WHERE 1 ";

    if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
        while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
            $id =  $query_row['id'];
            $hiragana = $query_row['hiragana'];
            $katakana =  $query_row['katakana'];
            $romaji =  $query_row['romaji'];
            $type =  $query_row['type'];
            echo "
                <table class='kana_table'>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            $id
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $hiragana
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $katakana
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $romaji
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $type
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            ";
        }
    } else {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Do you have `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in your header?

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Yes Mari. Thanks for the tip Jay.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out from this post : [UTF8 and Japanese characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006791/utf8-and-japanese-characters)

I had to use this function : mysql_set_charset("utf8");

Answer (score 0):

Please Ensure that....

1. Database Collation is set as "utf8_unicode_ci".
2. Set Html Meta charset UTF-8 in HTML  tag
   `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`
3. You can also use charset utf8 when query using `mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8 ");`

Hope it will help you