# Issue with Japanese Character store in MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, mariadb

Database informations_schema - 
[image]
This My Code

```
// Create connection 
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

 // Check connection 
if (!$conn) { 
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()); 
} 
$sql = "UPDATE table1 SET authorname='日本Delphi振興会 ヤマト運輸' WHERE id='1'"; 
$sql1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Database record is update successfully.

But data stored is garbage 
[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287252/mysql-insert-japanese-from-php-encoding-troubles?rq=1

Comment: That's [_Mojibake_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Comment: This question is not a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006791/utf8-and-japanese-characters -- This is Mojibake, that is Question Marks.